# Mystery 301 redirect?

Tags: php, api, rest

Im currently working on an REST api for an android application and for some reason the traffic seems to 301 Redirect to the same host which then 200 Accepts

Api: `global.mypanel.host/api/login`

Sending `{"username":"user","password":"pass"}`

should (and does in testing) return a response. However when sending from the android app the data is sent to the api BUT it 301 Redirects to the same host, same url, same api end point But doesnt pass the data..

Im scratching my head and my Google-foo isnt cutting it. SOS.

edit: its worth noting that using online tools to test the api works fine, redirect-checker tools also show that it only goes 200 and not 301 first.

https://global.mypanel.host/api/login
301 Moved Permanently
https://global.mypanel.host/api/login/
200 OK

WHY?

Answer (score 1):

The URLs are **not** identical.  The second one has a backlash appended to it.  Your website is redirecting the URL without the backslash to the one with the backslash.

There are also errors in php

```html
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: username in <b>/home/u450885603/domains/mypanel.host/public_html/startupshow/global/api/login/index.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: password in <b>/home/u450885603/domains/mypanel.host/public_html/startupshow/global/api/login/index.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
```

Comment: Im using folders is there a way to prevent the trailing slash  being addrd?

Comment: It should be possible.  I was not able to do that.  In the end, I decided that it was probably an advantage.  Perhaps you should ask a new question and post information on your server - if it's apache then post a copy of your htaccess file.  You could tick my answer to indicate that it's correct.